# MVC HandleError attribute not working on Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am experimenting with the relationship between Elmah and MVC's plumbed in exception handling, and am surprised at the outcome of the following code.  This is a brand new, straight from project template MVC application, and I have only added Elmah modules and handlers to the web.config.  And of the course the 'throw':

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        throw new Exception("Just for you Elmah!");
        return View();
    }
```

Break when error is thrown is set to off, yet the debugger still breaks.  When I continue I get a YSOD, and an Elmah error log, but it seems `HandleError` is doing nothing.

**JUST IN**
I didn't think I had to have custom errors turned on, as I thought that was only for 'my' unhandled errors.  I guess MVC is just as much a client of that service as I am.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619582/asp-net-mvc-handleerror-not-catching-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to start [ASP.net MVC [HandleError] not catching exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619582/asp-net-mvc-handleerror-not-catching-exceptions) and then onto the logging [How to get ELMAH to work with ASP.NET MVC [HandleError] attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Check HandleErrorAttribute is added to the GlobalFiltersCollection in the Global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFiltersCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Applying the filter globally is the equivalent of adding the attribute to each action. If I apply it to only one action and it doesn't work, applying it to all actions will only have it not working everywhere.