# How to display attribute error messages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an attibute

```
public class RequiresAdminRights : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            User user = User.Load(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!(user.IsInRole(Role.Administrator)))
                    throw new Exception("You need admin rights to access this resource.");
            }
        }
    }
```

In my controller I have

```
[Attributes.RequiresAdminRights]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The user logged in doesnt have any admin right and the RequiresAdminRights throws an exception.  How can I display the exception message?

Comment: I wouldn't throw an exception but rather redirect the user to a page that either requires them to log in or presents them with an access denied message before redirecting them back to whence they came.

Comment: MY difficulty here is how and where to redirect the page, can I have an example please

Answer (score 0):

Throw a custom exception like `PermissionDeniedException`, create a base Controller class and define like this.

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(PermissionDeniedException), View = "Login")]]
public class BaseController : Controller
{

}
```

Your controller should now extend this class. 
Also, don't forget to turn On the customErrors in your web.config.

Now, everytime you throw and `PermissionDeniedException` the user will be redirected to  "Login" View. Another option is to redirect the user to a "Permission Denied View" that will explain to your user that he needs to log in before accessing that page.

For more details you can check this other SO questions.

1. [ASP.NET MVC HandleError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183316/asp-net-mvc-handleerror)
2. [ASP.net MVC [HandleError] not catching exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619582/asp-net-mvc-handleerror-not-catching-exceptions)