# HandleErrorAttribute derived class is not catching exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes, handleerror

I have a ASP.NET MVC web app and I am trying to improve its error handling capabilities.  I read up on the HandleErrorAttribute base class and wanted to use that with my controller classes.  However, when I throw a test Exception from a method in one of my controller classes that is decorated with that attribute, the **OnException** override in my derived class is *not* triggered.  Instead of my derived error handling class's OnException method being triggered, I see a generic error message in XML format and the generic error message is *not found anywhere in my app*:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note I tried adding the following custom errors element to the *system.web* element in my **web.config** file as indicated by this SO post, but *it didn't help*:

[ASP.net MVC [HandleError] not catching exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619582/asp-net-mvc-handleerror-not-catching-exceptions)

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

Here is my HandleErrorAttribute derived class:

```
public class HandleControllerErrors : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Breakpoint set here never hit.

        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, "Controller", "Action");

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
        {
            // Use the ErrorInController view.
            ViewName = "ErrorInController",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model)
        };
    }
}
```

Here is how I decorate my controller class.  I have a method in it that forcibly throws an exception that is *not* inside a *try/catch* block.:

```
[HandleControllerErrors]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Api/TestException/")]
    public IHttpActionResult TestException()
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException("Fake invalid cast exception.");
    }
}
```

Comment: So MVC or Web API app? Or both? Even if both, which part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ApiController is not the same as an MVC Controller, and as such this will probably not work. Error handling is handled a bit differently in Web API. Check the following link for exception handling attributes for Web API:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I created a ExceptionFilterAttribute filter attribute to handle Web Api Controller exceptions.  Too bad you have to have two different error handling mechanisms for Web Api Controllers and everything else.  But that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the global filters:

```
 filters.Add(new HandleControllerErrors {View = "Error"});
```